# How to initialize replicaset remotely on mongoDB on a Kubernetes environment

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am trying to deploy MongoDB on my Kubernetes cluster.

I am deploying it in a few different steps where the first one will include the config-svr replicated  , the second will include the shards replicated and he third will inc;ude replicated router pods.

I was able to create a kubernetes statefulset of 3 config pods but now I have to initialize the replica set.

I understood that I need to use rs.initiate() method in order to initialize the replicaset but I can't do it from remote.

my installation is all automatic and in which I can oinly run kubernetes job for the deployment and i cannot run exec command in any script.

I tried using a remote mongo pod job with the --host flg but I get an error message indicating admin is not authorized:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetInitiate: { _id: \"crs\", configsvr: true, members: [ { _id: 0.0, host: \"mongo-config-0.mongo-config-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:27017\" }, { _id: 1.0, host: \"mongo-config-1.mongo-config-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:27017\" }, { _id: 2.0, host: \"mongo-config-2.mongo-config-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:27017\" } ] } }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

I read that I need to give my admin user read/write permissions but that will require again doing 'exec' commands inside the pods manually ( or via external script ) and I can't do that.

I also tried using the kubernetes api with ServiceAccount token permissions inside a pod job but I found that it is not possible to use curl with exec  api since it requires a web session unlike other kubernetes api commands.

was any one able to initialize mongoDB replica either but using some Mongo workaround or Kubernetes workaround?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This works for me from outside of pod:

```
kubectl exec PODNAME-mongo-0 -- bash -c 'mongo localhost:27017 --eval "rs.initiate({_id:\"YOURREPLICASETNAME\",members:[{\"_id\":1,\"host\":\"YOUR-NODE-1-NAME:27017\",\"priority\":10}, {\"_id\":2,\"host\":\"YOUR-NODE-2-NAME:27017\",\"priority\":5}]})"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used fqdn of statefullset which was mongodb-0.mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017 to connect mongodb by mongosh

```
mongosh.exe  mongodb://localhost:30145  --eval "rs.initiate({_id: 'rs0', version: 1, members: [     { _id: 0, host : 'mongodb-0.mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017' }]})"  --authenticationDatabase admin
```